# Check textarea it contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working on the editor templates [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) I want to check if the tags have been added in the format eg `{title}` to later be able to replace them when viewing the template.

Unfortunately, or checks me just correct one tag, or if there is a word before the tag also indicates not correct.

The problem also is the situation when the tag is entered using the HTML editor, then it is in the form `<p> {title} </p>` and also does not properly validate the form.

I'm trying to somehow overcome, but poorly

```js
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
  var val = this.value;
  var my = $(this).val();
  if ( val.search(/{event_title}/) == 0 ) {
    $( "p.eventTagTitle" ).addClass( "true" );
  } else {
    $( "p.eventTagTitle" ).removeClass( "true" );
  }
  if ( val.search('{event_form}') == 0 ) {
    $( "p.eventTagForm" ).addClass( "true" );
  } else  {
    $( "p.eventTagForm" ).removeClass( "true" );
  }
  if ( val.search('{event_author}') == 0 ) {
    $( "p.eventTagAuthor" ).addClass( "true" );
  } else {
    $( "p.eventTagAuthor" ).removeClass( "true" );
  }         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="eventTag eventTagTitle">title</p>
      <p class="eventTag eventTagForm">form</p>
      <p class="eventTag eventTagAuthor">author</p>
      <style>
       .eventTag {color:red;}
       .eventTag.true {color:green!important;}
      </style>

<textarea type="text" name="eventTemplateBody" class="form-control" id="eventTemplateBody"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the solution below:

I had to change green to blue so I could see if it was working and I dropped the `!important` tag.

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .eventTag {
        color: red;
    }
    .eventTag.true {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<p class="eventTag eventTagTitle">title</p>
<p class="eventTag eventTagForm">form</p>
<p class="eventTag eventTagAuthor">author</p>
<textarea type="text" name="eventTemplateBody" class="form-control" id="eventTemplateBody"></textarea>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('textarea').keyup(function() {

    var input = $(this).val();

    // CHECK TITLE
    if (input == "{event_title}") {
        $(".eventTagTitle").addClass("true");
    } else {
        $(".eventTagTitle").removeClass("true");
    };

    // CHECK FORM
    if (input == "{event_form}") {
        $(".eventTagForm").addClass("true");
    } else {
        $(".eventTagForm").removeClass("true");
    };

    // CHECK AUTHOR
    if (input == "{event_author}") {
        $(".eventTagAuthor").addClass("true");
    } else {
        $(".eventTagAuthor").removeClass("true");
    };

    // TEST OUTPUT TO CONSOLE
    console.log(input);

});

</script>
```

Comment: thank you but it's not this. when add tag {event_title} is validate green, when add tag {event_title} and spaccing or {event_title} {event_form} = not working

Comment: i need check all tags is required.

Comment: similar solution in php stripos() when i have string and in array keywords must to be in string / true or false